# Using Excel 2016 Power Query to Perform Conditional Inner Join

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have two tables in Excel 2016

- a `Vendor` table and
- a `Transactions` table.

I'm trying to do something like this from [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) but in Power Query's Formal Language (M):

```sql
SELECT * FROM Transcations
INNER JOIN Vendor ON Vendor.Name LIKE '%' + Transactions.VendorName + '%'
```

It's a simple query in SQL. But, merges in Excel seem not to allow conditional inner joins. Can anyone help with this, M, code?

```vb
let Source = 
  Table.NestedJoin(Transactions,{"VendorName"},Vendors,{"Name"},"Vendors",JoinKind.Inner)
in
    Source
```

Here's some sample data:

```
Table Vendors
|  Name      | PeopleCount    |
| ---------  | -------------- |
| ACME       | 35             |
| Microapple | 2000           |
| Happyworx  | 62             |

Table Transactions
| TransactionID | VendorName                | Amount |
| -----------   | ------------------------- |------- |
| 1             | Xaction: ACME             | $19.50 |
| 2             | Microapple 5/27 -- RYXTU  | $32.75 |
| 3             | Microapple 5/30 -- KJDIU  | $7.23  |
| 4             | Xaction: ACME             | $22.32 |
| 5             | Happyworx Store 7362      | $3.23  |
```

These tables need to be joined on `Transactions.VendorName LIKE '%' + Vendor.Name + '%' (if M has a wildcard delimiter)`.

Comment: Could you upload sample data? And for Join the Tables which key field you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "Dummy Merge Key" column to both queries, e.g. = 1.  Then I would start from the Transactions Query and add a Merge with the Vendors Query, matching on that "Dummy Merge Key" column. Then Expand all the Vendors columns.

At this point you have a massive "cross-join" of all Transactions rows crossed with all Vendors rows. Don't panic.

I would then add a Conditional column to check your criteria e.g.

Vendor Matched

= If Vendors.Name Contains VendorName then Yes
Else No

Then Filter for Vendor Matched = Yes.

Performance is surprisingly good.